# No Icon but it can be tested

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, widget

I am practicing Flutter by following this [5th section](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-app-testing/#5). I don't see `Icons.close` in the app. But for unknown reason it can be tested

**Question:**
Is document missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the code, the page that is begin tested is the '[lib/screens/favorites.dart](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/testing_codelab/step_07/lib/screens/favorites.dart)'. You can check this in the test description

```
group('Favorites Page Widget Tests', () {
```

Please see the code below which confirms that the favorites page does add a trailing  IconButton with Icon.close icon.

```
trailing: IconButton(
          key: Key('remove_icon_$itemNo'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
```

Whereas the screenshot posted by you along with the question seems to be of the Home Page '[lib/screens/home.dart](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/testing_codelab/step_07/lib/screens/home.dart)'. This can be confirmed from the following code on the Home Page, which shows a Icons.favorite icon if the item is within the favoritesList or shows a Icons.favorite_border icon if not within the list.

```
    trailing: IconButton(
      key: Key('icon_$itemNo'),
      icon: favoritesList.items.contains(itemNo)
          ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
          : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
```

The docs are not missing anything. Happy learning

Comment: My bad. I comes from Django/ReactJS. I though it was single page